# From Excel 2010 is it possible to attach a PDF file to a list item.

Tags: list, excel, attachments, vba

I have the list item ID and I have the location of the PDF file, it is created using the excel sheet and now I want to attach it to a list item.

Answer (score 2):

Try working with this code snippet. This assumes you have an SPWeb and SPList open:

```
var item = list.GetItemById("your_item_ID");
var file = web.GetFile("URL_of_your_file");
var bin = file.OpenBinary();
item.Attachments.Add("Attachment Title", bin);
item.Update();
```

Merry Christmas :)